# How to retrieve data from Dictionary class in java

Tags: java, dictionary

I have created the object of Dictionary class and i am inserting values in it. and on displaying i am getting all the values that i pushed in the dictionary. but while searching i am unable to get particular key value pair from dictionary.

```
class Demo{
        static String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int ch=0,num=0;
            String dictionary,contactName,contactNumber,relation;
            Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println(newLine + "Dictionary in Java" + newLine);
                System.out.println("-----------------------" + newLine);
                System.out.println("Adding items to the Dictionary" + 
                newLine);
                Dictionary dict = new Hashtable();
                while(ch!=4){
                System.out.println("1. Insert Contact Details\n2. Display  
                Contact Details\n3. Search Contact Details\n4. Exit");

                System.out.println("Enter Your Choice:");
                ch=Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

                switch (ch) 
                {
                case 1:
                        System.out.println("How many Contacts you want to 
                        insert:");
                        num=Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
                        for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
                            {
                            System.out.println("Enter the name of Contact Number 
                            "+(i+1)+":");
                            contactName=in.nextLine();


                            System.out.println("Enter the Contact Number of 
                            "+contactName+":");
                            contactNumber=in.nextLine();
                                dict.put(contactName, contactNumber);
                            }

                        System.out.println(newLine + "Items in the 
                        dictionary..." + dict + newLine);
                        System.out.println("-----------------------" + newLine);
                         break;
                case 2:
                        System.out.println(newLine + "Items in the 
                        dictionary..." + dict + newLine);
                        System.out.println("-----------------------" + newLine);
                        break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Enter Name you want to search:");
                    String name=in.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(dict.get(name));
                    break;
                }
}
```

And this is my output:

```
Dictionary in Java

-----------------------

Adding items to the Dictionary

1. Insert Contact Details
2. Display Contact Details
3. Search Contact Details
4. Exit
Enter Your Choice:
1
How many Contacts you want to insert:
2
Enter the name of Contact Number 1:
qwe
Enter the Contact Number of qwe:
123
Enter the name of Contact Number 2:
asd
Enter the Contact Number of asd:
12332

Items in the dictionary...{qwe=123, asd=12332}

-----------------------

1. Insert Contact Details
2. Display Contact Details
3. Search Contact Details
4. Exit
Enter Your Choice:
2

Items in the dictionary...{qwe=123, asd=12332}

-----------------------

1. Insert Contact Details
2. Display Contact Details
3. Search Contact Details
4. Exit
Enter Your Choice:
3
Enter Name you want to search:
1
null
```

please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine, but you're entering the wrong search term. Instead of entering `1`, you should have entered either `que` or `asd`, the names of the contacts.

If you want to print both name and contact number, then change your println as it will only print what you tell it to. Change this:

```
System.out.println(dict.get(name));
```

to this:

```
System.out.println("Name: " + name + ", contact: " + dict.get(name));
```

or something similar.

Comment: but i want to search whether that "que" name exist or not? so how should i search it in dictionary

Comment: @ParagBhingre: you enter `que` and if it exists, it will return a contact number -- try it and see. Entering in `1` for a contact name makes no sense, since there is no contact name named `1`.

Comment: and if exist then how to retrieve both name and contact.

Comment: @ParagBhingre: then print both name and contact -- you're code is only doing what you tell it to do. Change that println to also print the name, simple as that.

Comment: i am searching for name and if exist i want both name and contact number and i am unable to to that.

Comment: @ParagBhingre: come on now, it's simply a matter of adding the name to the println. See edit to answer ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93026/discussion-between-parag-bhingre-and-hovercraft-full-of-eels).